# ImportError: cannot import name saxexts

Tags: python, xml, ubuntu, sax

I want to use a python script on my Ubuntu 10.04 64 bit but I find no way to make it work because of the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 24, in <module>
    from xml.sax import saxexts
ImportError: cannot import name saxexts
```

I understand that this is someway related to SAX python libraries, but I can't find where this package is under ubuntu.
I've searched under synaptic but no python-sax related package or similar.

Any idea of what's going on?

Comment: where/when are you getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"saxexts"** is not a part of the normal sax lib. You can look [here](http://www.koders.com/python/fidFFE4CF2E5110E306F73EF5994A49E1F40E7DE11D.aspx?s=SAX#L2). Its an experimental extension.

Answer (score 2):

@Stony is right, by default saxexts is not included in Python xml package. To fix it, you have to add the module to the sax package, i.e. copy `saxexts.py` (You may get it from [Koders page](http://www.koders.com/python/fid77F4A703EEFA623DC8F155A8C7D712395274F961.aspx?s=SAX#L2) provided by @Stony) to someplace like `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/saxexts.py` (depending on where you or Ubuntu has Python installed).

Answer (score 1):

I think you must install python xml,

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyxml/

maybe this will help